# In url rewriting, why is the postback giving the wrong url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am experimenting with URL Rewriting. The first time it displays with the correct url. After perfroming any event handling, the form posts back, and then it has wrong url.
Like the page url is `http://devweb.tsgdomain.com/nphnewdemo/Enewsletter/68` and when i click url button then it gives wrong url `http://devweb.tsgdomain.com/nphnewdemo/Enewsletter/popup.aspx?name=dev-test-please-review-it` insted of this url `http://devweb.tsgdomain.com/nphnewdemo/popup.aspx?name=dev-test-please-review-it`.

Please suggest some answers to why this is happening (and how I can make this work correctly).

Comment: Add dome code and fix grammar and spelling

Comment: Add some code and fix grammar and spelling.

Comment: k i correct it.pls give me reply

Comment: Could you please list some of your code so that we can figure out where you're going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: m using this example to use url rewriting'http://sharpertutorials.com/clean-url-structure-in-aspnet/`

Answer (score 0):

This is happens because the form is rendering using the actual URL (and not what user see).

If you like to change that you can be rewriting the form attribute making a global handler of the form.

Here is a full solution that is tested and working.

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid39B3A4A2AD871AA78E7E5D8643A076EF4352CDF9.aspx

In the aboce code the line that make the change is the

```
value = Context.Request.RawUrl;
```

Comment: m using this example to use url rewriting'http://sharpertutorials.com/clean-url-structure-in-aspnet/`